# Separate osgi bundle serving sun.misc package

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I have an apache-felix platform running on java 11 and one of my bundles require google protobuf library which require sun.misc package. Unfortunately protobuf is not yet compatible with java11, so it won't work with that version of java. What i want to do is to create separate bundle with sun.misc package copied from earlier versions of java and other bundles could import this bundle. Are any other simpler solutions to solve this problem ?